# How to make phone numbers into clickable links in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In Android development, I'm able to use the [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) object to transform a phone number into a clickable link that will present the phone's dialler to the user.

Is this possible with Windows Phone? If so, how can I make a phone number into a clickable link?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is PhoneCallTask http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

[PhoneCallTask MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

What you could do is make a textblock that looks clickable. Then on its click event launch the PhoneCallTask

```
PhoneCallTask pct = new PhoneCallTask();

pct.PhoneNumber = "1112223333";
pct.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to apply a style to a text which is detected to be a number?

If i guest what are you trying to do, then create a style for your text and do this:

```
if (var something == phonenumber) //think of a logic to detect that
{
    something.Style = (Style)this.Resources["YourStyleKey"];
}
```